# Typescript type guard that only partially narrows

Tags: typescript, typeguards, type-narrowing

I am trying to make a type guard that narrows the `string` type but doesn't narrow it all the way to an explicit list of strings.

Here is an example of the type of code I am writing:

```js
type Node = { type: string, content: string };
type Macro extends Node { type: "macro" };

function generateGuard(filter: Set<string>) {
    function strGuard(s: any): s is Macro & {content: unknown} {
        return typeof s === "object" &&
                  s.type === "macro" && 
                  filter.has(s.content);
    }
    return strGuard;
}
const isMacro = (s: any) => typeof s === "object" &&
                            s.type === "macro"
const specialMacro = generateGuard(new Set(["x"]));

let xxx: Node = {type: "macro", content: "some string" };

function task1(){
    if (isMacro(xxx)) {
        if (specialMacro(xxx)) {
            // Do something for special `Macro`
            xxx;
            // ?^ Macro
        } else {
            // Do something for non-special `Macro`
            xxx;
            // ?^ never
        }
    } else {
        // code for non-macro `Node`
    }
}

function task2(){
    if (specialMacro(xxx)) {
        // Do something for special `Macro`
        xxx;
        // ^? Macro
    }
}
```

The issue is that `xxx` has type `never` in the `else` block. I want it to have some sort of `T extends Macro` type instead (or a the full `Macro` type would be fine, it just cannot be `never`). The `& {content: unknown}` doesn't narrow the type because `{content: string}` is already more specific.

Is there some way to type `generateGuard` such that it narrows `{content: string}` by some "unknown" amount?

Comment: Given your example, I'd say that your guard could narrow to a "pattern" template literal type like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weQPKw) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply, to notify me)

Comment: Ignore the `startsWith` (TypeScript won't consider it for the check), the only thing that TypeScript will consider for the guard is `is string`. Thus if the guard succeeds the returned type will be a string. In your case you are passing a string (and TypeScript knows it), thus in the `if` you know that it's a string, in the `else` the guard says it's not a string, but you defined it as a string, the resulting type is then `never`

Comment: @jcalz Unfortunately, in my actual code I am not testing for a prefix, but testing whether a string is in a set that's been passed to me. I've edited the example to be more realistic.

Comment: Why is this a type guard at all?  What are you going to do with `xxx` if the guard returns `true` that you can't do if it returns `false`?

Comment: In my actual use case, I am filtering nodes in an AST. I have a filter function that filters by the `.type` and the `.content` of a node, but currently returns a type guard based only on the node's `type`. I'd like something like `node is Macro & {content: unknown}` but that type guard is the same as `node is Macro` since `{content: string} & {content: unknown} == {content: string}`

Comment: Could you [edit] the example code to demonstrate something closer to what you're trying to solve?  Maybe with a definition of `Macro` or whatever the actual problem is?  Right now I don't understand why you are narrowing in either case... what specifically goes wrong if the return type of `specialString` is just `boolean` and not a type predicate? If the code shows the problem it would be easier to advise.

Comment: If you look at [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NdrkdW) where `strGuard()` just returns `boolean` instead of `s is XXX`, you'll see that (of course) `xxx` stays of type  `Macro` in both branches of the `if` statement.  If that doesn't meet your needs, could you [edit] your code to show exactly why?  Why does it matter if the compiler narrows `xxx` to some subtype of `Macro` or not?  Without this information, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz In my actual code I do a check to make sure `xxx` is type `Macro`. Then I do a further check based on `strGuard`, after the first check.

Comment: And do either of these checks require the TypeScript compiler to understand that `xxx` is any narrower than `Macro`?  You say you are looking for a type which is narrower than `Macro` in some difficult-or-impossible to specify way.  But you haven't shown, with code, why this matters. Please [edit] your code so that you are doing something with `xxx` where you currently have "Type Macro" which does not work *unless* `xxx` is of a type *narrower than `Macro`*.  I'm not sure how else to ask you for this, and I'm concerned that you haven't understood what I'm asking for.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I was trying to not clutter the example with details. I have updated it so that hopefully it makes sense to you now. There are three conditions I need to handle: When `xxx` is a `Macro` that is special, when it is a non-special `Macro`, and when it is not a `Macro`. I don't want typescript to infer that `xxx` is `never` in any of the branches.

Comment: And my question was... why is the "special" `Macro` something the compiler should care about?  I've updated my example to [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXq3kN); where you have a type guard which can narrow `Node` to `Macro`, but `specialMacro()` just returns `boolean` and does no narrowing in either branch.  I have yet to see something that actually goes wrong with code like this here.  You've done is show the type of `xxx`, but you're not doing anything with it.  If you can't demonstrate code where `fn(xxx)` only could or should compile if `xxx` is a "special" `Macro`, then I'm stumped.

Comment: @jcalz Updated again. `specialMacro` is part of an API and may be used on its own, so it also must be a type guard.

Comment:  If it's important that the compiler be able to distinguish between `Macro` and (let's say) `SpecialMacro`, then you should show code that actually cares about this difference.   But so far all of your "do something with `xxx`" code is just looking at the type of `xxx` and not actually *doing something*.  I think we are probably at an impasse and should stop engaging further; sorry. Maybe someone else will come along and help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're hiding several interesting bits from TypeScript. By specifying that the set is a set of distinct string types you can get the narrowing you want without introducing a too-specific constraint in `content` in the `false` case:

```js
type AstNode = { type: string, content: string };
type Macro = AstNode & { type: "macro" };

function generateGuard<C extends string>(filter: Set<C>) {
    function strGuard(s: any): s is Macro & {content: C} {
        return typeof s === "object" &&
                  s.type === "macro" && 
                  filter.has(s.content);
    }
    return strGuard;
}
```

Usage now works:

```js
const specialMacro = generateGuard(new Set(["x", "y", "z"]));

let oneNode: AstNode = {type: "macro", content: "some string" };
if (specialMacro(oneNode)) {
    // `oneNode` is type Macro
    oneNode.content // and content is of type "x" | "y" | "z";
} else {
    // Type AstNode
    oneNode.content;  // and content is of type `string`
}
```

See it in action [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggzsAcgewCbQLxQN5VJALigQCcBLAOwHMAaKAY2QuAmaNMqqgF8BuAKHzQAsgEN6JZFCzwkaaADIcecBCIAiALbjJ6ngP4AzAK4V6wMkyhVWEEqJYBxY6JKoAPAGEoEAB4sKVDhiYHJqAD4ACkMyABsWEiIAZQhgL3CAShx+KFyoEzMLK1JnV1RIuCJRChAM9igyYLEJKSVsRmZWYCJPbmy8gagSVOMSChVIZENiaQwsdWQAIwArCHM9BQUcwZ2duAA6IVn57RaNpW3dq-y4hP2AC1E4Cv2OgOAMgQHuS6GRsZCJFKbgEPw6CGIkHoZFEsWakmk1ls9icLjckQoEAA7lAUsBIgBtdS+dR0dQgUlQdQAL3UAF0Mp9+PxYqkoL4OURZCh0IjsEINKddHQ3l0NHBkJpoBxqHo+PwyNMKlCYXCdMhIhzfIz+nkAPR6qAAFVUUHhyF+WteTHeoJ8sTg0GwvwNxtN3Pklo51s6zFBQA)

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is that I don't have access to a const array of strings to define the type. Modify your example and set `let oneNode: Macro` and use `Set(["a", "b", "c"] as string[])` and the issue will return.

Comment: @JasonSiefken it seems clear by now that you can't use a solution in which the compiler actually figures out what's "special" about a special macro. But I don't understand why you want the compiler to try. What, specifically, goes wrong if `specialMacro()` returns `boolean` and doesn't narrow at all?

Comment: What goes wrong is that `oneNode` in the else branch is `never` and typescript says it is an error to access the `.content` attribute of `never`.

Comment: No, I asked "what goes wrong if `specialMacro()` *does not narrow at all*"?  If you make it return `boolean` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9nK1m), then it isn't `never` in the else branch.  Do you understand the question now or is there still a communication issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcAKAnApsGADwB5NFdCpcwATdRdKbGMAcwD4AKR7ALgaYtWAGkQAHPAUL9MASn49EMegAMAJAG9MAX008h2lYg0AoROcR4oIbEigBPMbjjAB2RAF4viAOT62PogAZEFuAHSMqNhQ6ADqMFDInBL4RLIA3CbaJjS4EAA2UbiIEAiMiABC2Ki0-OAwAI4gxej2ALYARnD5mQ5OiACSNJ5uQsHGANpVNTQAugD8-D4wND7ZoJCwCEroQ9xMCoJs8m47g8OmFpa41raIAIT3PGFtqFAQSQD0AHoAOgDuAGo1J8MlkTCZ8jdEIRYYQRgAidBwNotI6sBGIDAlMpQTIwVycNBYSREThwwiiPwo3A+WSyYxmCwUzJXT6fRDfeZZcj5dDFS7MuGsizsznc7IExBEjA4VKEclwqnIhB0hmC8wspnmMVcnm4PkC7Uw4XG3USyHQuH2RHI1GjNgI-GE4lyqSKwj2Kn-DCremMq7WkU6jl67S8-kBoWe4OIc3gqWcZR7a3+jUmmNm0MSiNGwOw+yx+PaIA)

```
function hasPrefix<P extends string>(str: string, prefix: P): str is `${P}${string}` {
    return typeof str === 'string' && str.startsWith(prefix);
}
declare const Brand: unique symbol;
type Id = string & {[Brand]?: 'id'}
function isId(str: string): str is Id {
    return !!str.match(/^\w+$/);
}

let xxxx = "some string" as const;
if (hasPrefix(xxxx, 'some')) {
    xxxx;
    // ^?
} else {
    xxxx;
    // ^?
}
if (hasPrefix(xxxx, 'soon')) {
    xxxx;
    // ^?
} else {
    xxxx;
    // ^?
}
let xxxy = "some string";
if (hasPrefix(xxxy, 'wasd')) {
    xxxy;
    // ^?
} else {
    xxxy;
    // ^?
}
if (isId(xxxy)) {
    xxxy;
    // ^?
} else {
    xxxy;
    // ^?
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is happening here?

Comment: A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) of this code would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I have to sleep so "no u" (community wiki)

Comment: That's a neat example. Unfortunately, in my actual code I am not testing for a prefix, but testing whether a string is in a set that's been passed to me.